# what is the mean of probability density function

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a PDF
$$p(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\exp \left(\frac {-(x-1)^2}{2}\right) + \exp \left(\frac {-(x+1)^2}{2}\right)\right)\right] \quad\text{for}\; -\infty  < x < +\infty$$

Can we say that the mean of the above is $0$ and variance is $1$?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Variance of the weighted mixture of two gaussians](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16608/what-is-the-variance-of-the-weighted-mixture-of-two-gaussians)

Comment: nice question.  i think it'd be better if made more general -- i.e., you could have asked for methods to compute the mean and variance of any arbitrary PDF, instead of just this particular PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign "mean" to be the expected value of the random variable $X$ whose distribution is your PDF, and you can assign "variance" to be the expected value of $(X - \mathrm{mean})^2$.  Specifically:

$$\mathrm{mean} = E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: x \, p(x) $$

$$\mathrm{variance} = E[X-E(X))^2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: (x-E(X))^2 p(x) $$

**EDIT**

Using these, I find the mean to be 0 and the variance to be 2.

I will say, however, that these concepts are a little sketchy if the distribution is truly bimodal.

Comment: *Sketchy*? Really?

Comment: @did: Really.  It is a term of rigor in Australia, where I lived for a time.

Comment: There is nothing sketchy there, neither in the Australian meaning of the term nor in any other I can think of.

Comment: I was making a statement about bimodal (and multimodal) distributions, where concepts that fit nicely with a simple normal distribution don't work so well in general.  It may be OK here, though.

Comment: I know what you meant, and I reacted to it because this is deeply wrong: expectations and variances are perfectly well defined for (suitably integrable) multimodal distributions. (And I do not think your answer addresses the OP's question.)

Comment: @did: they are well defined, sure, as I laid out above.  I implied nothing else.  But what exactly do they mean?  Perhaps I am approaching this from a physics point of view, where it becomes crazy to speak of a width of a beam whose intensity has several deep peaks.  Here, such distinctions may not be meaningful.

Comment: Also, I gave the OP a tool by which to compute the mean and variance.  I can fill in the details if he asks.

Comment: @Did you say Ron Gordon has not addressed the OP's question.  are you saying that these definitions of mean and variance are wrong?

Comment: @dbliss Huh? What makes you think I would have said such a thing?

Comment: @dbliss "And I do not think your answer addresses the OP's question." $\ne$ "these definitions of mean and variance are wrong". Say, what are you after, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_X$ denote the PDF of a random variable $X$, $(x_k)_k$ a collection of real numbers, and $(p_k)_k$ a collection of nonnegative real numbers summing to $1$. Then, 
$$
g:x\mapsto\sum\limits_kp_kf_X(x-x_k),
$$ 
defines a PDF and a random variable with this PDF is $Y=X+Z$, where $Z$ is independent of $X$ and $\mathbb P(Z=x_k)=p_k$ for every $k$.

In particular, $\mathbb E(Y)=\mathbb E(X)+\mathbb E(Z)$ and $\mathrm{var}(Y)=\mathrm{var}(X)+\mathrm{var}(Z)$.

In your case $X$ is standard normal and $Z$ is $______$, hence $\mathrm{var}(Y)=$ $______$.